# CodeLite - "Program exited with return code: -1073741510"

Tags: c, codelite

I just installed CodeLite on my laptop, and when I try to run the basic hello world from a new project

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't return 0 but instead `Program exited with return code: -1073741510`.

My laptop had already MinGW installed. I then tried to install CodeLite on my desktop computer (which didn't have MinGW installed, so I installed it)... and got the same issue.

I feel like i'm forgetting something obvious.

Comment: 'FFFFFFFFC000013A'

Comment: Oddly enough, Microsoft says of error code  "0xC000013A: The application terminated as a result of a CTRL+C".  (I guess saying SIGKILL would be a giveaway)

Comment: I knew it was something stupid. :( Thanks guys.